# Configure RollingFile writer in 4.x version of Serilog.Sinks.File

Tags: c#, .net, serilog

The `RollingFile` sink was slipstreamed into `Serilog.Sinks.File` from version 4.x onward (as far as I can tell). I'm trying to configure it via appSettings like, but no log files are showing up...

Here's a repro.

1. Create a new .NET 4.6.2 Framework Console Application
2. `Install-Package Serilog`
3. `Install-Package Serilog.Sinks.File`
4. `Install-Package Serilog.Settings.AppSettings`
5. Add this to `App.config`:

```xml
<appSettings>
  <add key="serilog:using:RollingFile" value="Serilog.Sinks.File" />
  <add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile" />
  <add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.outputTemplate" value="{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level:u3}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"/>
  <add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.pathFormat" value="log-{Date}.txt" />
</appSettings>
```

6. Add this to `Main` in `Program.cs`:

```csharp
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.AppSettings().CreateLogger();
Log.Logger.Fatal("Does it work!?");
```

7. Run it!

After that:

- Result: no log files in `/bin/debug`
- Expected: some `log-{date}.txt` file in `/bin/debug`

If I change `RollingFile` to `File` everywhere in the XML, and `pathFormat` to `path`, a file *is* placed in the expected location.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wups, you need to use `write-to:File` everywhere now, and specify a `rollingInterval` on the `File` sink.

Found that this works:

```xml
<appSettings>
  <add key="serilog:using:File" value="Serilog.Sinks.File" />
  <add key="serilog:write-to:File" />
  <add key="serilog:write-to:File.outputTemplate" value="{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level:u3}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"/>
  <add key="serilog:write-to:File.path" value="log-.txt" />
  <add key="serilog:write-to:File.rollingInterval" value="Hour" />
</appSettings>
```